# PHP - Remove element from multidimensional String

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following string Available:

```
$flatPath = '0/instances/0';
```

With this information I want to be able to unset the element from a multidimensional array like this:

```
$array = [['instances' => [1,2], ['instances' => [3,4]]
```

Therefor the Result should look like:

```
$array = [['instances' => [2], ['instances' => [3,4]]
```

Statically it would look like:

```
unset($array[0]['instances'][0]);
```

I want to be able to remove items in any given string path if available in the array.
Therefore the solution has to be able to remove any item from a multidimensional array, irrespective of the structure of the `$array`, as long as the `$flatPath` exists.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627252/php-make-multi-dimensional-associative-array-from-a-delimited-string would be a starting point.

Comment: I tried the code snippet, but nothing happened at all. Thanks anyways.

Comment: As I mentioned - it's a starting point, you would need to amend the code to do the exact thing you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627299/1213708 as a starting point, this code follows the process with a few tweaks.

Exploding using `/` to split the string into it's parts, then it removes the last key so it can `unset()` that particular value from the layer above.  Then it loops through the keys to find the layer above, and unsets the appropriate value...

```
$keys = explode('/', $flatPath);
$endKey = array_pop($keys);
$arr = &$array;
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $arr = &$arr[$key];
}
unset($arr[$endKey]);
unset($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you. But the result is not `$array = [['instances' => [2], ['instances' => [3,4]]`

Comment: What do you get as the output?

Comment: @Sandor Farkas The provided solution produces the [desired outcome](https://3v4l.org/RoPpl) - what exactly do you mean _But the result is not..._?

Comment: Great job @NigelRen ! Thank you, i checked the wrong $variable as output....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function check_diff_multi($array1, $array2){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$array2)){
            if(is_array($val) && is_array($array2[$key]) && !empty($val)){
                $result[$key] = $this->check_diff_multi($val, $array2[$key]);
            }
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}



        $dane = array(array('instances' => [1,2]), array('instances' => [3,4]));
        $flatPath = '0/instances/0';
        
        $test = array();
        foreach (array_reverse(explode('/', $flatPath)) as $value)
        {
            if(empty($test))
            {
               $test = array($value => '');
            }
            else
            {
                $test = array($value => $test);
            }
        }
        
        var_dump(check_diff_multi($dane, $test));
```

method check_diff_multi comes from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261512/14912402

Comment: You might want to add the [source @fdrv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246039/multidimensional-array-difference-php) of the function you're using.

Comment: Bat @Sandor Farkas the author of the post does not respond :(